# Why is my command function not being called when I press a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm a bit of a newbie to Tkinter, so bear with me. I'm making a simple game which involves buttons laid out in a grid. When one of these buttons is press, depending on their position, they move to a different spot on the grid. I feel like the mistake is probably a really small one but it continues to escape me.

All code relevant to the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *

class MoveableButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, location, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.location = location
    
    # the function I hope to call
    def move(self):
        self.location = "new location"
        self.grid(column=self.location[0], row=self.location[1])

root = Tk()
pieces = [MoveableButton("location_coordinates", root) for i in range(24)]
for i, piece in enumerate(pieces):
    piece.command = piece.move #the source of the problem

[piece.grid(column=i%5, row=i//5) for i, piece in enumerate(pieces)]
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the beginning of `move` does it get hit?

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately

Comment: However breakpoints show that the command attribute of the button is move, so it should be called when pressed

Comment: It would help if you created a [mcve] that didn't rely on external images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never assign a command to the button. You set the `command` *attribute* on the python object, but that's not the same as setting the option for the actual widget.

You need to remove `piece.command = piece.move` and add `piece.configure(command=piece.move)`

Comment: Just for clarification sake (to improve my understanding of Tkinter widgets), do you happen to know why piece.configure(command=) needs to be used rather than piece.command=. Does command behave differently from other Widget Button attributes in some way?

Comment: @user17301834: no, command doesn't behave differently from other widget attributes. `piece.x=y` won't work for any widget attribute. As to why, tkinter simply wasn't designed to work that way.

Comment: That explains things, thx